# SQL Server : unexpected behaviour in while, when using INSERT INTO

Tags: sql-server-2008

I guess this is going to be a very easy one for anyone who knows SQL programming...

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/66ae2/3)

Here is the code I am executing against the database:

```
DECLARE @maxCounter int
-- Used to get the maximum bound number for my loop, basically what is the highest number of records. Tested, seems to work as expected.
SET @maxCounter = (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(SN)
                   FROM TestResults 
                   WHERE Type = 'EX'
                   GROUP BY SN
                   ORDER BY COUNT(SN) DESC)

CREATE TABLE #Info
(
    DLoc VARCHAR(500),
    DCode VARCHAR(500),
    Dobs VARCHAR(500)
)

DECLARE @counter INT
SET @counter = 1

WHILE @counter <= @maxCounter 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Info (DLoc) 
    VALUES ('Location_' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(16)))

    INSERT INTO #Info (DCode) 
    VALUES ('Code_' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(16)))

    INSERT INTO #Info (Dobs) 
    VALUES ('Observation_' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(16)))

    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END

SELECT * FROM #Info;

DROP TABLE #Info;
```

If you see some weird things in the code, then that is because I am a total beginner and do not know any better.

Expected output of the while loop:

```
+------------+---------+---------------+
| defLoc     | defCode | obs           |
+------------+---------+---------------+
| Location_1 | Code_1  | Observation_1 |
| Location_2 | Code_2  | Observation_2 |
| Location_3 | Code_3  | Observation_3 |
+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Unexpected output result:

```
defLoc           | defCode     | obs           |
-----------------+-------------+---------------|
Location_1       |             |               |
                 | Code_1      |               |
                 |             | Observation_1 |
Location_2       |             |               |
                 | Code_2      |               |
                 |             | Observation_2 |
Location_3       |             |               |
                 | Code_3      |               |
                 |             | Observation_3 |
```

I have no clue where the empty cells come from...

Comment: INSERT inserts a row. You have three inserts, each inserting a row. In each you say “I want a row with this column set to this value and others have their default values.” You want to have a single INSERT with all columns that you want on that row in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **ONE** `INSERT` for each iteration, and specify **all three columns** and their values in one go:

```
WHILE @counter <= @maxCounter 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Info (DLoc, DCode, Dobs) 
    VALUES ('Location_' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(16)),  
            'Code_' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(16)),
            'Observation_' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(16))
           )

    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

Each `INSERT` will insert a **whole row** - the value you provided is inserted into the column you specified, but the **other columns** will all remain `NULL`.

Comment: Keeping this as the answer, since it was the first one that solved my issue and is also understandable to me. Stupid beginner's mistake! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can insert each row with 3 different column values with a single insert statement in a loop:

```
WHILE @counter <= @maxCounter
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Info (DLoc,DCode,Dobs)
    VALUES (
          'Location_' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(16))
        , 'Code_' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(16))
        , 'Observation_' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(16))
        );
    SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END;
```

Alternatively, you could insert all rows at once in a single `INSERT...SELECT` statement using a tally table as the source. If you have no tally table, you can use a CTE to generate the set of numbers. The example below uses a `CTE` with `ROW_NUMBER()` that can be extended as needed.

```
WITH 
     t10 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t1k AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t10 AS a CROSS JOIN t10 AS b CROSS JOIN t10 AS c)
    ,t1m AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS num FROM t1k AS a CROSS JOIN t1k AS b CROSS JOIN t1k AS c)
INSERT INTO #Info (DLoc,DCode,Dobs)
SELECT
          'Location_' + CAST(num AS VARCHAR(16))
        , 'Code_' + CAST(num AS VARCHAR(16))
        , 'Observation_' + CAST(num AS VARCHAR(16))
FROM t1m
WHERE num <= @maxCounter;
```

In SQL Server, set-based operations generally outperform procedural looping constructs by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Dan! I kept marc_s' answer, since it was the first one and basically did resolve my issue. Even though I find your second reply very interesting, I am unable to follow it right now. I simply lack the deeper understanding of SQL. If you have the time, would you mind explaining it further? This might also help other newbies who come by this in the future. How do the 3 lines between 'WITH' and 'INSERT' work? Especially the first line @ t10 doesn't mean anything to me 8-[